# Excel - If cell contains a certain string, then add content to another cell

Tags: excel, formula

Its been a while since I used Excel. 
If a cell, say 'A1' contains the word 'Test', can I create a formula to add content to 'B1' which will add the text 'Dave'... then is it possible for the remaining rows to use the same action?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
=IF((IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("TEST",A1)),0,SEARCH("TEST",A1)))>0,(A1 & " Dave"), "")
```

You would just change TEST and Dave to what you would like and you can fill it down in Column B